# Query records created in last 1 hour in UTC format

Tags: php, datetime

Records have a createdDateTime flag in this format "**2016-09-05T11:39:12Z**"

I want to filter out records created in last 60 minutes. How do I accomplish this in PHP?

It's a rest api from which I am querying data.

My request looks somewhat like this

```
$filter=createdDateTime gt datetime'2016-09-05T11:39:12Z'
```

createdDateTime is in UTC format as said. I just want gt datetime'**last1 hour timestamp in UTC format**'

With the following command I can generate timestamp in the stored format.

```
gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z");
```

Comment: What are you trying to query? MySQL table? Provide more information.

Comment: It's a REST api from where I am querying data.

Comment: It's a ISO_8601 formatted datetime. Do you need method to make a valid Datetime object from this format ?

Comment: Hi, Updated my question

Answer (score 0):

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');  // this may not be necessary for your case

$createdDateTime='2016-09-05T11:39:12Z';  // sample from OP
if(strtotime($createdDateTime)>=strtotime("-1 hour")){  // compare Unix timestamps
    echo "filter out: $createdDateTime";
}else{
    echo "process: $createdDateTime";
}
// output: "process: 2016-09-05T11:39:12Z"           <-- since stamp is >6 months old
```

Comment: @ShivanshuGupta  If this answers your question please award it the green tick so future SO readers can benefit.  If it is flawed or I am misunderstanding your question please leave me a comment that explains the trouble and I'll try to fix the code.